# How to add timestamp to kafka 10 messages with nodejs

Tags: node.js, timestamp, apache-kafka, node-red, kafka-producer-api

I re-wrote a Kafka producer node in node-red using nodejs.
I noted Kafka10 added feature about attaching timestamp on messages sent to producers but I found just java examples.
How can I add timestamp to messages using nodejs ?

In the following I report how producer is implemented in nodejs:

```
function kafkaAdvancedNode(config) {
    RED.nodes.createNode(this,config);
    var topic = config.topic;
    var partition = config.partition;
    var clusterZookeeper = config.zkquorum;
    var debug = (config.debug == "debug");
    var node = this;
    var kafka = require('kafka-node');
    var HighLevelProducer = kafka.HighLevelProducer;
    var Client = kafka.Client;
    var topics = config.topics;
    var client = new Client(clusterZookeeper);

    try {
        this.on("input", function(msg) {
            var payloads = [];

            // check if multiple topics
            if (topics.indexOf(",") > -1){
                var topicArry = topics.split(',');

                for (i = 0; i < topicArry.length; i++) {
                    payloads.push({topic: topicArry[i], messages: msg.payload});
                }
            }
            else {
                if(partition == "" || !partition)
                    payloads = [{topic: topics, messages: msg.payload}];
                else
                    payloads = [{topic: topics, messages: msg.payload, partition: partition}];
            }

            producer.send(payloads, function(err, data){
                if (err){
                    node.error(err);
                }
                node.log("Message Sent: " + data);
            });
        });
    }
    catch(e) {
        node.error(e);
    }
    var producer = new HighLevelProducer(client);
    this.status({fill:"green",shape:"dot",text:"connected to "+clusterZookeeper});
}
```

On google I found just this:[link](https://blog.mimacom.com/blog/2017/04/07/apache-kafka-with-node-js/)

but actually I don't understand how to integrate in my code (what's Avro?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think kafka-node supports the 0.10 Kafka protocol so it's not likely to support timestamps on messages.

For this (and other) reasons I wrote something similar using node-rdkafka and published it as node-red-contrib-rdkafka. See https://github.com/hjespers/node-red-contrib-rdkafka

UPDATE: I just published a new version (0.2.0) of node-red-contrib-rdkafka that supports either 0.10 "event time" or "processing time" timestamps as well as dynamic topics, keys, and partitions.

Comment: Unfortunately, on raspberry pi I receive an error trying to install it.
link -> http://imgur.com/a/idV4U

Comment: I see, you didn't mention this is running on a raspberry pi. This error is probably due the embedded librdkafka library written in C. I also wrote a pure JavaScript node-red-contrib-confluent module for use on embedded devices like the rPI. It uses the Confluent REST Proxy to pub/sub to Kafka. This would set the timestamp automatically as ingestion time. It also works better through firewalls and over the internet because it uses HTTP up until the Proxy and limits Kafka protocol to inside the data center / cloud.

Comment: Not good for me, my timestamp are incapsulated in sensor data which are JSON-LD

Comment: Why do you need the event time in the Kafka message timestamp if you already have it in the sensor data in the message body? Is this for use in Kafka Streams or something else that requires the event time vs publish time to be on the Kafka 0.10.x message itself? I'm asking because there are ways (i.e. single message transforms) to hoist the timestamp out of the message body and apply it as the Kafka timestamp for downstream processors.

Comment: I was curious about use of this kafka feature, also because Flink (my consumer) fully supports the feature extracting automatically that timestamp.

Comment: If Flink can extract times from the message body then it shouldn't matter what time stamps (if any) are on the outside envelop of the Kafka message. Kafka time stamps are used for message retention, and for Kafka Streams apps. I will however try and get node-red-contrib-rdkafka to compile on the raspberry pi  and to enhance it to allow manual setting of Kafka protocol timestamps.

Comment: The underlying JavaScript node-rdkafka library supports keyed message publishing but I haven't exposed it in node-red-contrib-rdkafka yet. It's on the TODO list. It should be easy to add since I already added keyed publish in node-red-contrib-confluent.

Comment: updated the answer to reflect the addition of timestamps and key/value messages in node-red-contrib-rdkafka. I also talked to the author of librdkafka and he believes it should work on Raspberry Pi so I'm going to go ahead and try to get this new version working on rpi as well.

Comment: @AndreaGiordano I just tested node-rdkafka and node-red-contrib-rdkafka on my Raspberry Pi and it works like a charm. I'm running the standard Raspbian Jessie with the node-red than comes with the distro. I had to install a few of the required OS packages to get it to compile with SSL, SASL, L4Z compression, and all the librdkafka bells and whistles. It's working with time stamps and can even talk to Kafka 0.11